# robot_localization not generating odom to robot's sensor_frame transform

Tags: navigation, rviz, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm trying to fuse an IMU and a DVL (measures linear velocity on x, y, z). I have the following axis configurations.

- base_link : robot's frame
- base_imu :
  imu's frame
- base_dvl : DVL's frame

I have a transform broadcaster which broadcasts base_imu->base_link and base_dvl->base_link. The picture attached shows the frame poses. I have set the fixed frame as base_link here (rviz). [image: image description]

This is the TF tree:

[image: image description]

But when I run robot_localization, the localization is perfect but it doesn't show my sensor frames. There are also some warnings generated in rviz (check left pane), saying there isn't any transform to odom frame. But there is a transform as per the tf_tree. Here is a picture:
[image: image description]

How do I fix this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266435/robot_localization-not-generating-odom-to-robot%27s-sensor_frame-transform/) by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-07-16**:
The timestamp on the different transforms look ways too off for me.They should happen nearly at the same time. Do you run ros across different computers? If so check the current date and time both.

**Comment by [lffox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20121/lffox/) on 2017-07-18**:
Hi, Thanks for your reply. The timings don't matter to me much since they are just static transforms. But can  that be cause for this issue?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-07-22**:
The ROS nodes do not know that the transforms do not change. When they are outdated they are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using a static transform publisher, but you appear to be using the static transform publisher from `tf`, and not `tf2_ros`. Is that correct? The time stamps are going to matter in this case, and it appears that they are almost 5 days apart. I'd switch to the static transform publisher in `tf2_ros.`

If you already are, I'd give some more details about your setup, including posting the launch files. Is all of this running on the same machine?

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1